# How do I create a makefile clean for a program with multiple directories

Tags: c, makefile

I need to create a makefile for my C program. The code is devided in 3 directories like the following example:

main.c

controllers

- listatarefas.c
- listatarefas.h

models

- tarefas.c
- tarefas.h

views

- cli.c
- cli.h

For reference I'm working on a Windows 10.

The make file I first wrote is as follows:

```
CC = gcc

CFLAGS = -Wall

LDFLAGS =

OBJFILES = main.o .\views\cli.o .\models\tarefas.o .\controllers\listatarefas.o

TARGET = Lab_02_APP

all: $(TARGET)

$(TARGET): $(OBJFILES)

    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $(TARGET) $(OBJFILES) $(LDFLAGS)

clean:

    $(RM) $(OBJFILES) *~
```

But after running the command 'make clean' I receive an error message saying:

```
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, rm -f main.o, ...) failed.
make (e=2): System couldn't locate specified file.
make: *** [clean] Error 2
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It is *probably* the case that the problem is that you are telling `rm` to remove a file that doesn't exist, and the solution is to add the `-f` flag, which tells `rm` to ignore such absences: `$(RM) -f $(OBJFILES) *~`. It is also possible that the variable `RM` doesn't contain what you think it does. The next step is to show us the actual command Make is trying to execute, which should appear in the output ("rm main.o .\views\cli.o...").

Comment: Please format your error messages as code as well so it's readable.  And please include ALL the error output, don't elide it with `[...]`: we need to know what command actually generated the error.

Comment: Based on the format of your error message you are running on Windows (please always include this information in your question).  The default value of the `RM` variable is `rm -f` which is a POSIX tool, that does not exist on Windows by default.  You either need to change this variable to use a Windows program like `del` or whatever, or else install a POSIX shell environment (from MinGW or Git for Windows or something like that).

Comment: Just edited. I followed what MadScientist said and it worked perfectly. Thanks for the advice. Thank you all!

Comment: minor nit: it seems inappropriate to remove `*~` files in the `clean` rule.  `clean` should only remove files that are created by `make`, not files that are created by an external editor.  If I am working on a `new-feature.c` that `make` does not know about, I would not want `make clean` to blow away ancillary files that my editor has created.

Comment: What toolchain are you using (where do you launch *GCC* from)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make is telling you that the command `rm` was not found.  Either install it or use a Windows specific command `del` perhaps by setting the variable `RM = del /q`.